# Solving $\min\int_{0}^{1} \left( x^2 + 2tx + tx\dot{x} + \dot{x}^2 \right) {\rm d} t$ with $x(0)=0$ and $x(1)=1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

> Solve $$\min\int_{0}^{1} \left( x^2 + 2tx + tx\dot{x} + \dot{x}^2 \right) {\rm d} t, \qquad x(0)=0, \quad x(1)=1$$

---

We need to solve the problem with the Euler Equation

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial\dot{x}}\right)=0$$

We define $F$ as

$$F(t,x,\dot{x})=x^2+2tx+tx\dot{x}+\dot{x}^2$$

Then subsequently we have:

$$ \begin{aligned} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} &= 2x+2t+t\dot{x} \\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial\dot{x}} &= tx+2\dot{x} \end{aligned} $$

When substituting this into the above mentioned equation: $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}-\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial\dot{x}}\right)=0$, **my** final equation becomes $\ddot{x}-\frac{1}{2}x=t$ which is incorrect recording to the Student's Manual. The correct 'answer' should be $\ddot{x}-\frac{1}{2}x=\frac{1}{2}t$. Could someone point out where I made a small/big mistake?

Comment: You are right, the manual has a typo.

Comment: Euler or Euler-Lagrange?

Comment: From my understranding it is Euler, but I could be wrong since I am just learning.

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange equations correspond to the an extremum of the action, e.g. the integral you want to minimize, but it doesn't say if it's a minimum or a maximum. One needs to evaluate the sign of the second variation to decide. See for ex.: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Second_variation#:~:text=From%20Encyclopedia%20of%20Mathematics,in%20the%20calculus%20of%20variations. In this case, one can show there is a lower bound to the integral, but I am not sure if that would be sufficient to show that the EL eqs. correspond to the minimum of the action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac12x^2+tx\dot x$ is a complete derivative, so is constant for all admissible functions $x$ satisfying the boundary conditions. So it can be removed from $F$. The task reduces to
$$
\min\int_0^1(\tfrac12x^2+2tx+\dot x^2)dt
$$
This reduced task
has now no mixed terms between $\dot x$ and the state $(t,x)$, the Euler-Lagrange equation reads directly
$$
2\ddot x=x+2t.
$$